# Need some support in writing factorial function using Recursion

Tags: recursion

I need to write a factorial function that takes in one input and returns the factorial of the given number. if the function is passed in to be 0 or less than 0 then the function should return 0.

I am not actually sure how to write this only using the features of  PSScript version 1.0 however I just wrote this, please can someone help me.

JAVA -

```
public static int factorial (int n) {
      if (n<0) {
          return 0;
      }
      return (n<2) ? 1 : n *factorial(n-1);
}
```

I want to know if there is any I could write this so could use this to write a function in PSScript version 1.0

This is what I have done so far ;

```
func fac (int n) return int  {
     if (n<0){
         return 0;
     }
     else 
     {
     return (n<2) ? 1 : n *factorial(n-1);
     }
}
```

Comment: PSScript refers to what? PowerShell, PostScript, PhotoShop, something else?

Comment: PSScript is a fictional development language which has a limited set of functionality that allows it to be used to perform specific tasks. It comes in two versions; 1.0 and 2.0. These versions each build on the functionality of the previous version to provide more features.

Comment: I have been asked to do this and been given a documentation about this development language [Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yiugitzdvgs70l5/PSScript%20Language%20Reference.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: First line of the Introduction on that link ***"PSScript
is a fictional development language"***.  I take it this is an interview question, or homework.  You can't expect us to just do your work for you...!

Comment: I am not sure if this is power shell. The link i have provided is reference to thier development language

Comment: I am not actually just asking question I have shown what I have done and I know people in the Stack Overflow won't do my homework or interview question for me, I am well aware of that

Comment: I'd recommend putting in the question the context in which your asking (i.e where the question comes from, how you got that fictional language spec), acknowledging the fact that "PSScript" is a fictional language and putting a link to its specification in the question (not just comments as they can be temporary).  Then people know what's going on, instead of spending time trying to work out what PSScript is - you present it like it is a common term i.e. "I  am not actually sure how to write this only using the features of PSScript version 1.0"

Comment: Okay thanks for the comment, I should have explained it much more better. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Based on the language spec you linked to I would guess the recursive factorial function would look like this in your fictional language:

```
func fac (int n) returns int  {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * fac(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Maybe it should check for negative arguments too.

Comment: What I have got is similar to this one but I have got an extra bit which checks for numbers below 0 so I guess that is the way of answering this question